# Why is my navbar and carousel not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

This is my text for the HTML currently. I am having difficulties with the carousel and can't get it to display images properly. On top of the carousel not working, I have an issue with my nav bar background color. It won't stay at 100% width. Going back to the carousel, When I try live view and click on arrows to go to next or prev, resets it's placement behind the NavBar.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Funky Munky Arcade</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initional-scale=1">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="container nav-container">

                    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                        <li><a href="#">Parties</a></li>
                    </ul>

                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a href="/index.html" class="navbar-left"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/UXms4Eq.png" class="logo"></a>

                </div>

                    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

        <!-- Beginning of Carousel -->


        <div class="carousel slide" id="bannerslides" data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- Indicators -->

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                <li data-target="#bannerslides" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                </li>

                <li data-target="#bannerslides" data-slide-to="1">
                </li>

                <li data-target="#bannerslides" data-slide-to="2">
                </li>

                <li data-target="#bannerslides" data-slide-to="3">
                </li>

            </ol>

            <!-- End of Indicators -->

            <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->

            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="item active">

                    <img src="https://db.tt/W08hePZ53h">

                </div>

                <div class="item">

                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/t0Y4JDI.png">

                </div>

                <div class="item">

                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zaUETSd.png">

                </div>

                <div class="item">

                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LRATkRS.png">

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- End of Wrapper -->

            <!-- Beginning of Carousel Controls -->

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bannerslides" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bannerslides" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>

            <!-- End of Carousel Controls -->

        </div>

        <!-- End of Carousel -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.nav-container {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: red;
width: 100%;
}
.head {
text-align: center;
}
.intro{
font-size: 48px;
text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron{
background-color: white;
font-size: 24px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top{
background-color: red;
border: 0px;
}
.logo{
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.carousel{
margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: "can't get it to display images properly" isn't a very good problem statement. How _are_ they displaying, and how were you _expecting_ them to display? Your example is incomplete, so if you're actually including jQuery and the Bootstrap JS files, please edit your question.

Comment: @Anthony Hulett, you could avoid downvotes if you make your question more clear, and stick to one question/topic per post. The nav bar background color is a separate issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add file javascript of bootstrapp

> Tip: Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual "carousel.js" file), or all at once (using "bootstrap.js" or "bootstrap.min.js").
>   [ref here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h)

Comment: I have a link to bootstrap file at the bottom and a call of function carousel. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: you check html exist file jquery.js ?

Comment: So I looked and the script for jquery wasn't there. I added it and it worked! Everything did. Thanks! Now to more researching.

Answer (score -1):

You need the CDN for jQuery.

That can be found at the jQuery website: https://code.jquery.com/

So this:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

would go in to the head of your page